# x86 assembly - How to use SHR to halve a negative number effectively?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I am using `SHL`/`SHR` in order to halve a number in a register. It actually works fine with both positive and negative numbers; however there is something that is bugging me about negative numbers.

Before I go on I should say I am aware of `SAR` and `SAL` to shift signed binary, but I need to use `SHL`/`SHR` specifically. (I did try `SAR` and `SAL` and those worked beautifully - but I can't use those)

So on to the problem.

If I have a number, lets say -5, which is stored in the register as "FFFFFFFB".

But when I `SHR` it (to halve it) it is being treated as if it was 4,294,967,291. It still works for my purposes, but instead of halving -5 (which would take 3 loops to reach 0) it halves this huge number and takes way more loops (32 loops). This bugs me as very inefficient. Is there a trick to making it see it as a -5 instead of 4,294,967,291?

I was thinking to check if the number is negative, store that in a register. Do work on it as if it was positive, then check my neg/pos register and assign the sign accordingly?

But that approach doesn't sound right to me?
But then again I am new to assembly and don't really know if thats the kind of thing I am expected to do for this type of problem?

Comment: If you know of `sar` then you know what it does. So, emulate it using `shr` and something else. PS: your approarch would work too. Don't expect anything "effective" since the effective (efficient?)  way is `sar`.

Comment: Mind you, this shift division is not correct for value -1 (sar -1 == -1, not zero). Otherwise the `sar` is the best solution for this. If you can't use `sar`, only other instructions, then you should study what `sar` does, and emulate it with other instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you will have to remember the sign bit:

```
MOV EAX,[TheValue]
MOV EDX,EAX
AND EDX,0x80000000    ; remember sign bit from EAX
SHR EAX,1
OR  EAX,EDX           ; and put it back
```

That will properly halve both positive and negative values. Result is in EAX.

Comment: Curious as to why the problem is there in the first place. Why is shifting right  also shift the sign bit and as side effect making it a huge positive number? Is it not it's only purpose (to store sign) in what case would it be useful to shift it out of position?

Comment: The sign bit is the top bit of, in this case, the 32 bit value. If you want to treat the value as unsigned, then the top bit is just that, the highest bit, not the sign bit. That is the nice thing about two's complement. And the unsigned value `0x80000000` can be halved by shifting it right once: `0x40000000`. In assembler, 32 bits are 32 bits and it depends on you if you want to treat them as signed or as unsigned.

Comment: @Duxa: You created this problem for yourself by insisting on `shr` (shift in zeros) instead of `sar` (shift in copies of the sign bit).  This code exactly emulates `sar eax,1` (plus clobbering EDX) and is 100% pointless unless you're just trying to understand SAR.  For normal people the problem doesn't exist; they use SAR to do a 2's complement arithmetic right shift.

Comment: @PeterCordes as mentioned in the original post `sar` is not allowed. Its a programming exercise that limits the tools at your disposal. If you had to hammer a nail and had a hammer, well then it wouldnt be meaningful, would it? What if you couldnt use anything made out of metal? Well then you may learn a thing or two along the way.

Comment: @Duxa: sure, learning exercises are fine, but you asked "why the problem is there in the first place", and wished for a shift that treated the sign-bit specially.  Like I said, that exists and it's called SAR so it's not a real problem. 
 Plus you want to shift in copies of the sign bit for 2's complement.  Only affecting the low 31 bits would be correct for a sign/magnitude arithmetic right shift.  (Except that would give it different rounding semantics: x >> 1` rounds towards -inf so `-1 >> 1` = -1, but `x/2` truncates towards 0.)  We also want a logical / unsigned shift, and that's SHR.